# Unable to submit form when having Login form

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms, angularjs-ng-click

I have the following code and I am unable to trigger - ng-submit or ng-click on this except local onclick function on login button. Please let me knjow if you know good solution or able to identify the problem:

```css
<form ng-submit = "login.submitLoginForm(login.user)" novalidate>
                <p>
                    <input class="username-email" type="email" name="username" value="" placeholder="Your Email"
                    ng-model="login.user.userName">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input class="password" type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"
                    ng-model="login.user.pwd">
                </p>
               
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="">Remember me</label>
                </div>
                
                <p> 
                    <button class="login" type="submit" name="Login" value="Login">Login</button>
                </p>
            </form>
```

```css
 vm.submitLoginForm = submitLoginForm;

        function submitLoginForm(user) {
            // submitLoginForm...
            console.log("UserName..form.." + user.UserName + 'pwd..' + user.pwd);

            if(user.userName != '' || user.userName != 'undefined'){
                vm.user.userName = user.userName;
                console.log("UserName..form.." + user.userName + vm.user.userName);
                ServiceFactory.setUserName(vm.user.userName);
            }
            if(user.pwd != '' || user.pwd != 'undefined'){
                vm.user.pwd = user.pwd;
                console.log("UserName..pwd.." + user.pwd + vm.user.pwd);
                ServiceFactory.setPwd(vm.user.pwd);
            }

            initialize();
            
        };
```

Comment: Try attaching `LoginCtrlr` with `ng-controller` in UI level..

Comment: I already have it in - route - config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider'];
    function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                controller: 'LoginCtrlr',
                templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
                controllerAs: 'login'
            })
            
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

Comment: Yea you have it, but just try also attaching it once to UI level. I had this problem earlier..

Comment: It did not help :( alos, I am able to call other functions in controller for $http etc. only click and form has problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
'use strict';

angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('LoginCtrlr', LoginCtrlr);

function LoginCtrlr() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.user = {
    userName: '',
    pwd: ''
  };
  

  vm.submitLoginForm = function submitLoginForm(user) {
    // submitLoginForm...
    console.log("UserName..form.." + user.userName + ' vm userName: ' + vm.userName);
    if (user.userName != '' || user.userName != 'undefined') {
      vm.userName = user.userName;
      console.log("UserName..form.." + user.userName + ' vm. userName: ' + vm.userName);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <section class="container" ng-controller="LoginCtrlr as login">
    <div>
      <p class="or">Or</p>
      <p class="login">your email</p>
      <form novalidate>
        <p>
          <input class="username-email" type="email" name="username" value="" placeholder="Your Email" ng-model="login.user.userName">
        </p>
        <p>
          <input class="password" type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" ng-model="login.user.pwd">
        </p>

        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="">Remember me</label>
        </div>

        <p>
          <button class="login" type="submit" name="Login" value="Login" ng-click="login.submitLoginForm(login.user)">Login</button>
        </p>
        <div>{{ login.message }}</div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <p class="note-text-center-xs">By continuing, you accept the terms of Use and Privacy Policy</p>

    <div class="login-help-center-xs">
      <p><a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
      </p>
    </div>

    <p class="no-account" onclick="#">You Don't have an account yet? Sign up</p>
    </a>
  </section>
</div>
```

I try to create the complete code snipped. the dependency module are removed since not all could access via code snipped.

What I change:

- define new 'app' module use [] (square bracket)
- You need to call the controller when you're assigning a object into a model, because you define all controller's method and attribute into it self rather than using $scope. for example:

  `<input class="username-email" type="email" name="username" value="" placeholder="Your Email" ng-model="login.user.userName">`

Comment: It partially resolved my problem. I am able to call submit now. But, its always telling me userName is undefined. <p>
                    <input class="username-email" type="email" name="username" value="" placeholder="Your Email"
                    ng-model="login.user.userName">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input class="password" type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"
                    ng-model="login.user.pwd">
                </p> and 
            console.log("UserName..form.." + user.UserName + 'pwd..' + user.pwd);

Comment: like the error told you. your userName variable is not define yet. If you take a look on my code I change that into string text. :)

Comment: I got that point, but it says - user.userName is undefined which is my function argument.

Comment: could you update your complete code? The other thing that I change comparing with your code is, you try to execute ng-click = "login.submitForm(user)". but with mine i change it become ng-click="login.submitLoginForm(login.user)". Why? because we only define submitLoginForm on the controller. and to passing object user as argument, again it need to specify the controller name. in my case i use alias 'login'

Comment: Updated / edited my code. Sorry, by nmistake, i edited your code too I think. Please ignore it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112031/discussion-between-smitha-and-mtamma).